# Google+ API - Posting a moment using PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-api, google-plus

I am using a Codeigniter Library (https://github.com/samwierema/google-plus-api-codeigniter), I can get the login credentials for a user and am storing the GooglePlusID and all access tokens in a DB.

My problem is that I am struggling to "Post a moment" on Google+, I've had a look through the code and suspect that it is quite old and may not have the option to do so.

I am currently trying

```
$google_plus_id = '';
$this->googleplus->people->insert($google_plus_id, 'vault', 'This is a test from my platform');
```

I have had a look at the "third_party" folder and cannot seem to find a mention of moment posting.

I am wondering if anyone has used the library and could possibly point me in the right direction of getting this to post / work.

Thanks

Comment: You have a number of issues with your code. Assuming the library still works. `$this->googleplus->people` is for interacting with people, you should be using `$this->googleplus->moments`. `me` is the only supported value of `$google_plus_id`. The [documentation specifies](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/moments/insert) that you should be passing an object with multiple values, not a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that the client library included in the project is completely out-dated, coming from a time where there weren't any moments available in the Google+ API yet.

You can get a newer version of the client library that should be compatible with the library you are trying to use from here: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/

If you exchange the files in the third-party folder with the new ones it should work.

It would be even better to update to the [newest PHP client library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) but this will most likely not be compatible with the Codeigniter Library...